# Doing an action after customer has clicked "place order" but before order is executed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Can someone please tell me what hook or filter i need to use to lead the customer to another page after they have submitted the order, like an "agreement page" (must be after "place order"). I would like them to completely filled out all the Billing, Shipping and CC info, click place order but my code will execute before the actual order is placed. and if successful "agreement" I will charge them, otherwise redirect back to checkout page

thanks,

J

Comment: Is this a home built ecommerce system or something like WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right.
After filling their form successful, you have store all date in array then initialize it to session variable then do the following.
1. show them something like this

Are real going to order product(s) below?

---

| S/N | Item Name | Quantity | price |

---

```
 _____       _____
| yes |     | no  |
```

If he/she click no then direct to checkout page else go to for order

Comment: problem is that I cant use sessions since they have submitted their credit card in, I just want to trigger an "action" before another action gets initialized